# Using ValueInjecter to map between objects with different property names

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, mapping, valueinjecter

How do I map a property from an object to another object with a different property name?

I have a `Product` class that looks like this:

```
public class Product : IEntity
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And the view model looks like:

```
public class ProductSpecificationAddViewModel
{
     public int ProductId { get; set; }
     public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

I need to do the following mapping:

```
Product.Id => ProductSpecificationAddViewModel.ProductId
Product.Name =>ProductSpecificationAddViewModel.ProductName
```

Here is my action method:

```
public ActionResult Add(int id)
{
     Product product = productService.GetById(id);

     // Mapping
     //ProductSpecificationAddViewModel viewModel = new ProductSpecificationAddViewModel();
     //viewModel.InjectFrom(product);

     return View(viewModel);
}
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using ValueInjecter then you would write a ConventionInjection. See the second sample [here](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=step%20by%20step%20explanation&referringTitle=Home)

```
    public class PropToTypeProp : ConventionInjection
    {
        protected override bool Match(ConventionInfo c)
        {
            return c.TargetProp.Name == c.Source.Type.Name + c.TargetProp.Name;
        }
    }
```

this injection will do from all properties of TSource.* to TTarget.TSource+*, so you do:

```
vm.InjectFrom<PropToTypeProp>(product);
```

Comment: ConventionInjection is not found anywhere in the world now.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easily with **AutoMapper**. By default is uses convention (i.e. Id maps to Id and Name to Name), but you can also define custom mappings.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductSpecificationAddViewModel>()
    .ForMember(destination => destination.ProductName,
               options => options.MapFrom(
                    source => source.Name));
```

Your contoller mapping code will be then this simple :

```
Mapper.Map(product, viewModel);
```

Comment: I know it's easy with AutoMapper but I can't use it on the web hosting servers because of the trust level, so I need to settle for ValueInjecter.

Comment: just curious here. what trust levels are required for Automapper on the server. Both are dlls right?

Comment: medium trust hosting service have problems with automapper because Reflection.Emit doesn't work in medium trust